# cURL request returns Resource Id#6

Tags: php, ajax, curl, https, cross-domain

I am trying to get link of an excel sheet which is generated by posting a cart to web server. I am posting data successfully getting the link for next AJAX GET call. When I try to execute cURL on next link, I am getting Resource Id#6 inplace of html response page.

I have attached an image for more details.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yCd4.png)

Comment: show your code what you have tried ? this stuff is not sufficient to give your answer

Comment: @BunkerBoy see my answer please.

Comment: your answer ? that means you have solved your problem ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy I just answered to show you my code. I did not post it in comment my mistake.

Comment: so please remove that from answer and update your question with that

Comment: $opts=array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>FALSE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>FALSE
    );

    $resp2_arr=reader_custom($link_for_ajax_post_2,$opts);

Comment: and my reader_custom() is as follow

Comment: function reader_custom($url,$opt){ // read from a link

    $feed_ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($feed_ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt_array($feed_ch,$opt);
    $ch_resp=curl_exec($feed_ch);
    $output = exec("curl ".$url);
    $ch_resp=set_links($feed_ch);
    $data=array(
        'resp'=>$ch_resp,
        'errno'=>curl_errno($feed_ch),
        'op'=>$output
    );
    curl_setopt($feed_ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    curl_close($feed_ch);
    return $data;
}

Comment: @BunkerBoy I have removed it.